# Get separate Lat and Lng Values from GeoJson file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am experimenting/learning how to use GeoJson data on a Google Maps Datalayer. I managed to get the co-ordinates to display in a popup by using `getGeometry().get()`.

Is there however a way to get separate `lat` and `lng` like you would with `latLng.lat(), latLng.lng()` or would I have to use something like regex to split it to lat and lng?

I am currently only able to get co-ordinates like this:

```
var coordinates = Event.feature.getGeometry().get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.get()` function returns a LatLng[*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.Point), so you should be able to call `.lat()` and `.lng()` directly on it, or `.toString()` or any of the [LatLng methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), e.g. this should work:

```
var coordinates = Event.feature.getGeometry().get();
var lat = coordinates.lat();
var lng = coordinates.lng();
```

Comment: I'm slightly embarrassed at having missed that! Thank you so much duncan, I appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Bruno no problem!